# JUnit testing hibernate validation in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, validation, junit

I have little pet project, it can make daily schedule for students and teachers. Now I've added hibernate validation in my project. When application work and I enter wrong value into field I got message from my messages.properties but when I am trying testing this validation I got default message from validator.

I have test

```
public class ClassroomValidationTest {

    private static Validator validator;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setUp() {
        ValidatorFactory factory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        validator = factory.getValidator();
    }

    @Test
    public void givenClassroomWithNotValidAddress_whenClassroomValidatedByValidator_thenValidatorGiveMessageAboutWrongAddress() {
        String wrongAddress = "W";
        Classroom classroom = new Classroom(1, wrongAddress, 5);

        Set<ConstraintViolation<Classroom>> constraintViolations = validator.validate(classroom);

        assertEquals(1, constraintViolations.size());
        assertEquals("Field size have to have from 2 letters to 150", constraintViolations.iterator().next().getMessage());
    }
}
```

and class model

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "classrooms")
public class Classroom {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 2, max = 150)
    private String address;

    @Column
    @NotNull
    @Positive
    private Integer capacity;
}
```

and I have messages.properties file with message

```
Size.classroom.address=Field size have to have from 2 letters to 150.
```

In Unit test I have other default message in local language.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Please could help me. Thank you for you time and sorry for my bad English :)

Comment: Have you added your message file in Test package resource folder?

Comment: Yes. I have messages.properies in test resourse folder.